# Will data members on a heap-allocated object be allocated on the heap or the stack?

Tags: c++

I am allocating a class object on heap, so all the data members will be on heap. But what if my class contains some data structure (e.g. `std::vector`) as a member:

```
#include <vector>

class Temp
{
public:
    std::vector<double> m_dPtList;
};

int main()
{
    Temp* pTemp = new Temp;
    pTemp->m_dPtList.Add(10.0);
    pTemp->m_dPtList.Add(20.0);
    pTemp->m_dPtList.Add(30.0);

    return 0;
}
```

Will the values `10.0`, `20.0`, and `30.0` be stored on the heap or on the stack?

Comment: Why does it matter? Note: Heap and stack are implementation details that are not relevant to object (it does not care where it is so why should you).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are data members allocated in the same memory space as their objects in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187797/are-data-members-allocated-in-the-same-memory-space-as-their-objects-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

pTemp is on the Heap.
You add into vector through value, so value is added into vector, vector on its own allocates storage on the heap. 
Case when contents would be on the stack is:

```
Class Temp
{

std::vector<double *> m_dPtList;

}

double temp = 10.0;
Temp* pTemp = new Temp();

pTemp->m_dPtList.Add (&temp);
```

Comment: Well, in that case the content of the vector is a `double*`, itself on the heap, but it happens to point to a value on the stack....

Comment: `pTemp` is not on the heap.  The object it points to is.  `pTemp` itself is an automatic, and is on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

`vector`'s buffer is always allocated on the heap, but in general, it's however the object was designed to be -- the immediate members will be allocated in the same place, but God knows where embedded pointers would point to.

Comment: Not 100% true. The vectors storage area is generated by the allocator. Where the allocator gets its memory from is undefined (though the default one will dynamically allocate the memory (ie it is of dynamic storage duration (though this does not mean heap as this is beyond the scope of C++ and is an implementation detail)))

Comment: Oops, sorry, forgot about the allocator parameter; thanks for the correction!!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `Temp`'s just wrapping `std::vector`.  You use `new` to create the Temp object, so it goes on the heap.  That object itself can be expected to contain a pointer to the memory in which the vector will store the data added to it... that will also be on the heap.  Summarily, only the `pTemp` pointer itself is on your stack.