# C++: Objects allocated on heap

Tags: c++

When we create an object using  *new* it is allocated on the heap. But, what happens to the members of the class that we are instantiating? For example,

```
class foo {
 Bar x;
 Bar *y;

 foo() {
   x = 10;
   y = new Bar();
 }
}
```

Here, x is an object while y is an instance of Bar. Are they both allocated on the heap? So if an object of foo *F* is created locally inside a method, what will happen to *y* when F goes out of scope?

Also, if *F* is created on the heap, when will we conclude that *F* is dangling (no one pointing to it)? Because, there may be no references to F but there may be references to *Y*.

Comment: That's why there are constructors and destructors.

Comment: Q: Here, x is an object while y is an instance of Bar. Are they both allocated on the heap? A: Yes.  y explicitly (in your constructor), x implicitly (along with "foo" itself).  Q: Also, if F is created on the heap, when will we conclude that F is dangling.  A: When you forget to "delete" the object you created with "new" ;)

Comment: @paulsm4: `y` is a pointer to `Bar`, not an instance of `Bar`.  `x` is an instance of `Bar`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are data members allocated in the same memory space as their objects in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187797/are-data-members-allocated-in-the-same-memory-space-as-their-objects-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are they both allocated on the heap?

Yes.

> So if an object of foo F is created locally inside a method, what will happen to y when F goes out of scope?

Nothing - the instance pointed to by "y" will stay put, since you don't have a destructor to provide your cleanup.  It'll effectively become a memory leak, unless something else references it (and cleans it up later).

> Also, if F is created on the heap, when will we conclude that F is dangling (no one pointing to it)?

It'll be dangling as soon as nothing points to it directly.  Something else pointing to `y` doesn't change the fact that `F` is no longer reachable.

This is why you really should use proper finalization in this case.  Without a call to `delete` matching every call to `new`, you will leak memory.

Answer (score 6):

They go along for the ride with the parent object, i.e., they are allocated dynamically or with automatic storage duration depending upon how the parent was initialized.  That does not necessarily mean that you need to deallocate each one separately though.

`x` in your case will be automatically deallocated when the parent object is.  However, `y` was allocated dynamically.   Therefore, it requires a separate deallocation.  Any call to `new` must be at some point followed by a call to `delete`.  This basic rule will help you reason about these situations.

As an aside, a pattern known as RAII ([Resource Allocation is Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)) should be used to manage the deallocation of your dynamically allocated objects (don't forget [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) though!).  You should also get into the habit of using initialization lists instead of using the body of your constructor to initialize objects, i.e.,

```
class foo {
 Bar x;
 Bar *y;

 foo() : x(10), y(new Bar()) { }

 // who deallocates y here?  Again, look into RAII
}
```

Comment: In this case, on `x` goes along for the ride with the parent, as `y` is always allocated via `new`. You should edit the start of your answer to be a bit more precise.

Comment: @StarPilot: I would say that is less clear.  The *pointer variable* `y` certainly goes along for the ride just as `x` does.  I clearly explain that what `y` points to still needs to be deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

Both `x` and `y` is allocated wherever the instantiator allocates the parent object `foo`. If `foo` was allocated as a local, both `x` and `y` will be allocated on the stack. If `foo` was allocated via `new`, then both will be allocated on the heap.

The object `y` is set to point at in the constructor of `foo` will always be allocated on the heap, as it is allocated via `new` in the default constructor.

As there is no destructor defined for `foo`, the object `y` points at will always leak. A destructor should be created for `foo` that will always `delete` the object `y` points at (when `y` is not null) to prevent memory leak. Although in practice, a smart pointer is often used in place of a bare pointer to prevent issues with default copy assignments and clone constructors.

Comment: No.  `y` will always be allocated along with the parent.  *What `y` refers to* will not be.  Also, probably best to think/speak in terms of storage duration rather than stack/heap as nothing in the C++ standard requires a stack and heap data structure to be used to implement different types of storage (though I realize they're so standard that I am being pedantic).  Also should mention the rule of three because, as soon as a destructor is added which `delete`'s `y` you may run into problems with assignments/copies.

Comment: I see your point. I'll update my entry as to not cause and further confustion.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of confusion in the terminology (may be due to Javaland ...)
In C++ variables are always "values" and pointers have "values" that are "addresses". Nothing more.
Compleptely different from C# or Java where variables are *references*, and all objects are on-heap.

Think to a pointer as "an object whose value is the address of another object".
At that point, `foo` just has two members that are created with it and leave inside it and with it:

- `x`, that is a `Bar` created inside the `foo` instance itself and ...
- `y`, that resides into the foo instance, and is *the address of a bar*.

What the address contained in `y` is, depend on what it is initialized/assigned.

- Can be `nullptr`,
- can be another `Bar` already existent (heap or stack or member of what, depends on you)
- can be another newly created Bar (via `new`, like in your sample)
- can be ... even x itself (via `&x`)