# C++ object heap allocated and member variable

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

```
class OtherClass
{
    ...
};

class Test
{
    OtherClass otherClass;
};

int main()
{
    Test *pTest = new Test;
}
```

`pTest` points to an object of type `Test`. Is `otherClass` allocated on heap aswell or in the stack?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are data members allocated in the same memory space as their objects in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187797/are-data-members-allocated-in-the-same-memory-space-as-their-objects-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Test *pTest = new Test;
```

Creates an `Test` object on Freestore(Heap), and all the members of `Test` are also on the same.
So Yes.

Note that technically, the standard never uses the terms Heap or stack but yes you can assume those because almost all implementations use them.

Comment: What if it was:  OtherClass *pOtherClass = new OtherClass;

Comment: @user1365914: Once you use `new` the object will be created on freestore and ur pointer is made to point to it.

Answer (score 1):

It's allocated on the heap. Since `pDataMember` is a data member with type `OtherClass` (not a pointer!), it is part of the memory allocated for the object of class `Test`, hence it will be located wherever the `Test` object is located.

Maybe you should not name a non-pointer `pDataMember`? That's confusing.