# Location of members of an object

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are data members allocated in the same memory space as their objects in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187797/are-data-members-allocated-in-the-same-memory-space-as-their-objects-in-c)

If I declare an object like this:

```
void main() {
  MyClass class;
}
```

it will be created automatically on the stack.

What happens if I do this:

```
class MySecondClass {
  private:
    MyClass class;
}
```

Will the member be created on the stack? If so, what happens if `MySecondClass` is created via `new`? Will this member still be on the stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will the member be created on the stack?

Yes.

> If so, what happens if `MySecondClass` is created via `new`? Will this member still be on the stack?

No. It will be stored along with the rest of the object, "on the heap" or wherever your free store is implemented, or wherever the object gets dynamically allocated (which could be some memory pool or something else).

It's worth noting here that the terms "stack" and "heap" are generally mis-used. What you're *really* asking is the following:

**Does the member have *automatic storage duration*?** Yes.

**Will it do so even when the encapsulating object has *dynamic storage duration*?** No — the *dynamicness* of the encapsulating object is, in a sense, "inherited".

> `[C++11: 3.7.5]:` The storage duration of member subobjects, base class subobjects and array elements is that of their complete object (1.8).

The practical location in memory in either case will be the stack and the free store ("heap") respectively, and that doesn't really matter.

And, by the way, `main` *must* have `int` return type.

Comment: Technically, the member does not have automatic storage duration. Subobjects have the storage duration of their containing objects.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Orly? Dammit.

Comment: Yes, see §3.7.5. I do get what you meant, but the words were not the right ones :/

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: That would seem to conflict with 12.1.7; quite clearly a `int a` member in a dynamically-allocated `T` ought to be treated within that `T`'s context as an automatic-storage object. Have we stumbled upon something horrible?

Comment: I don't think there's a contradiction. The storage duration is the minimum potential lifetime of the storage containing the object. (§3.7/1). The storage containing the subobject is part of the same storage containing the containing object, so it makes sense the two are the same. *Storage duration* is related to *object lifetime*, but not quite the same.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Okay; I'm just concerned about "cross-references" to this term in defining semantics elsewhere that may no longer be quite what I was expecting. I'll post a question about it.

Comment: So in one sentence: The compiler will manage the construction/destruction of the member.

Comment: @R.Martinho: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743727/are-there-any-unintuitive-side-effects-of-member-subobjects-inheriting-storage-d

Answer (score 1):

Yes, member is created on the stack.

If you create a  new object of MyClass using "new", resources will be allocated on the heap.