# Are there any unintuitive side-effects of member subobjects inheriting storage duration?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I didn't know this before, but [it turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743357/location-of-members-of-an-object/13743395#comment18884848_13743395) that:

> `[C++11: 3.7.5]:` The storage duration of member subobjects, base class subobjects and array elements is that of their complete object (1.8).

That means that `x->a` in the example below has dynamic storage duration.

I'm wondering whether there are any elsewhere-defined semantics that make reference to storage duration that imbue member `a` with different behaviour between object `*x` and `y`? An example would be the rules governing object lifetime.

```
struct T
{
   int a;
};

int main()
{
   std::unique_ptr<T> x(new T);
   T y;
}
```

And how about if `T` were non-POD (and other kinds of UDTs)?

In short, my lizard brain expects any declaration looking like `int a;` to have automatic (or static) storage duration, and I wonder whether any standard wording accidentally expects this too.

---

**Update:**

Here's an example:

> `[C++11: 3.7.4.3/4]:` [..] Alternatively, an implementation may have strict pointer safety, in which case a pointer value that is not a safely-derived pointer value is an invalid pointer value **unless the referenced complete object is of dynamic storage duration** [..]

On the surface of it, I wouldn't expect the semantics to differ between my `x->a` and my `y.a`, but it's clear that there are areas, that are not obviously related to object lifetime, where they do.

I'm also concerned about lambda capture rules, which explicitly state "with automatic storage duration" in a number of places, e.g.:

> `[C++11: 5.1.2/11]:` If a *lambda-expression* has an associated *capture-default* and its *compound-statement* odr-uses (3.2) `this` or **a variable with automatic storage duration** [..]
>
> `[C++11: 5.1.2/18]:` Every occurrence of `decltype((x))` where `x` is a possibly parenthesized *id-expression* that names **an entity of automatic storage duration** is treated as if `x` were transformed into an access to a corresponding data member of the closure type that would have been declared if `x` were an odr-use of the denoted entity.

and others.

Comment: And why "automatic or static" would be the most intuitive for your lizard brain?

Comment: @Kos: Because there's no `new` on the subobject

Comment: I think your lizard brain is less good at programming than the rest of your brain ;-). `x.a` has to be destroyed about the same time `x` is (immediately after x's destructor) , so it needs the same storage duration. If it had automatic storage duration (with what scope?) or static storage duration (kept until end of program) then that wouldn't be the case. And `int a;` *doesn't declare an object*. It declares a data member of `T`, which in turn leads to a subobject of `x`, but it is not truly "the definition of the object `x.a`".

Comment: Looking at it another way, objects have storage durations, and variable declarations bestow storage durations on the objects they declare. But `int a;` inside a class is not a variable declaration, it's a data member declaration. It doesn't have or need an associated storage duration.

Comment: @SteveJessop And what about in case of a e.g static member; isn't it also a data member _declaration_ or is it considered as a scope member declaration? It requires an associated storage duration, nevertheless. Maybe you should say: "it's an object member declaration"? But that feels wrong. I'm confused on terminology, even though I completely agree with you.

Comment: I've added some examples to the question of standard wording that I feel is "at risk" until someone proves to me that it's intuitive!

Comment: @Kos: No, but if you see `int a;` at global scope then it has static storage duration.

Comment: @iccthedral: well, static data members are objects, so they're different from non-static data members in the way that matters here. So possibly there should have been "non-static" weasel words at suitable points in my comments above. My point really is that `int a;` doesn't say "there's an object called `a`" in a class scope. Instead it says something more subtle, that each object of type `T` has a subobject called `a`. In a function scope or global scope it does says "there's an object called `a`", and `static int a;` does say that in class scope.

Comment: what does " that imbue member a with different behaviour between object *x and y" mean? Can you please clarify for non-native speakers?

Comment: Yes sometimes the term "automatic object" is used, and is clearly not intended for member subobjects. for example, the Standard can be read to allow NRVO here: `struct A { string x; string f() { return x; } }; int main() { A a; a.f(); }`. It can however also argued that the implicit this transformation transforms this to `return this->x;`. But clearly the designers of the wording didn't even *think* about this possible ambiguity, otherwise they would have clarified :)

Comment: The same thing BTW is true about temporaries: The Standard explicitly says that temporaries can have automatic or static storage duration (if they are created within a block or outside in namespace land). When I mentioned this possible ambiguity in the committee in the context of constexpr discussion (which has a flawed reference to "object with static storage duration", accidentally including temporaries), the guys that designed the constexpr wording were angry with me :)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Yep this is getting into the territory I'm interested in, now :)

Comment: `constexpr` was fixed to include everlasting temporaries, if I recall correctly.

Comment: yes i have noted the inconsistency in the lambda section too. but note that a nonstatic datamember being a  "variable" was an oversight in C++11. it will be fixed. but an "entity of automatic storage duration" still matches

Comment: @steve you are confusing object lifetime with object storage duration. a storage duration may well be longer than the object lifetime (and for class objects is true in practice, since a dtor call ends lifetime immediately and within the ctor the lifetime.has not yet begun). the standard could say "the storage duration of subobjects is equal to the one of their complete object safe for the name of that duration" and could remove the rule that any object has one of the named storage durations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This storage duration inheritance is what makes subobjects work. Doing anything else would simply be quite impossible. Else, you could not design any type that could be allocated both statically and dynamically.

Simply put, any violation of this rule would simply break everything.

Comment: What about things like initialisation semantics? Things that can be subtly different without "breaking everything".

Comment: Nope. An object is an object is an object and can be initialized the same way no matter where it's allocated.

Comment: Also, PODs or non-PODs, objects are objects. Asking about non-PODs is redundant.

Comment: @iccthedral: Not really; there are myriad areas of semantics that differ between the two. If that's not the case here then that's part of the answer, not redundant in the question. :)

Comment: @DeadMG: Okay, 8.5/11 explicitly gives objects of automatic and dynamic storage duration the same semantics in this way. Clearly the standard feels it's worth spelling it out. This is still just _one_ example -- can you demonstrate to me that there are not _other_ areas where the standard did _not_ imbue the same semantics, and that I might therefore get surprising (if subtle) differences between the behaviour of `x->a` and of `y.a`?

Comment: @Lightness: How can someone demonstrate that something *doesn't exist* in the standard without basically posting every other section of the standard? You can either take their word for it, or you can read the entire rest of the standard.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I'm quite aware that you can't prove a negative, especially when it comes to the C++ standards, but there must be some compelling argument. Especially given that the number of places the text "automatic storage duration" or "dynamic storage duration" is used is quite finite. It's almost at the point where you could analyse each feature that uses this wording and demonstrate that it does so in an intuitive fashion even in the scenario I presented.